# Conditionally delete line suffix and add prefix

Tags: java, filewriter

I have 4 lines:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17 1
812.12 135.14 646.18 1
812.12 135.14 646.19 2
812.12 135.14 646.20 2
```

I want to remove the last character of each line. Moreover, if the last character changes from previous line, `S` will be added in the front. For example, given the input above, the third line's last character is `2` which is different from `1` that terminates the second line. Therefore, `S` will be added in the front as shown below.

Desired output:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17 
812.12 135.14 646.18
S 812.12 135.14 646.19 
812.12 135.14 646.20
```

I have this piece of code to start:

```
while(lines[0].charAt(lines[0].length()-1)==lines[1].charAt(lines[1].length()-1)){
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Provide an example of the input *and the desired corresponding output.*

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: Why are you trying to do all of this? Maybe we could help you follow a different approach.

Comment: So help me please

Comment: I'm writing an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lines = new String[4];
    lines[0] = "812.12 135.14 646.17 1";
    lines[1] = "812.12 135.14 646.18 1";
    lines[2] = "812.12 135.14 646.19 2";
    lines[3] = "812.12 135.14 646.20 2";

    // first one is done separately to extract last character
    // for comparisons (for next iterations)
    char lastChar = lines[0].charAt(lines[0].length()-1);
    lines[0] = lines[0].substring(0, lines[0].length()-2);

    // start from index 1 since index 0 was already processed
    for(int i=1;i<lines.length; i++){
        // get last character
        char tmp = lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1);

        // remove last character
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length()-2);

        // if last character from this line isn't the same like
        // the last character from previous line, add S
        if(tmp != lastChar)
            lines[i] = "S " + lines[i];

        // update lastChar for comparison
        lastChar = tmp;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
        System.out.println(lines[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17
812.12 135.14 646.18
S 812.12 135.14 646.19
812.12 135.14 646.20
```

Or if you wish to have a function that takes `String[]` and modifies it:

```
static void updateLines(String[] lines){
    // first one is done separately to extract last character
    // for comparisons (for next iterations)
    char lastChar = lines[0].charAt(lines[0].length()-1);
    lines[0] = lines[0].substring(0, lines[0].length()-2);

    // start from index 1 since index 0 was already processed
    for(int i=1;i<lines.length; i++){
        // get last character
        char tmp = lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1);

        // remove last character
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length()-2);

        // if last character from this line isn't the same like
        // the last character from previous line, add S
        if(tmp != lastChar)
            lines[i] = "S " + lines[i];

        // update lastChar for comparison
        lastChar = tmp;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lines = new String[4];
    lines[0] = "812.12 135.14 646.17 1";
    lines[1] = "812.12 135.14 646.18 1";
    lines[2] = "812.12 135.14 646.19 2";
    lines[3] = "812.12 135.14 646.20 2";

    updateLines(lines);

    for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
        System.out.println(lines[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17
812.12 135.14 646.18
S 812.12 135.14 646.19
812.12 135.14 646.20
```

Comment: I hope u are still up because I need another help,

Comment: I have now the end numbers like this:

Comment: 1,1,10,10,100,100

Comment: if(lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length())-1>= '0'&&lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1)<= '9'){
                                                                                                               
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length()-1);

Comment: You want to delete everything after the last space?

Comment: If u can you can help me there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273979/how-to-check-2-charati

Comment: yes @Everyone like every thing but not before the last space

Comment: it still has a problem on line :

Comment: updateLines(lines);        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, index);

Comment: Please indicate what the problem says. I don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String[] lines = new String[]{
        "812.12 135.14 646.17 1", 
        "812.12 135.14 646.18 1", 
        "812.12 135.14 646.19 2", 
        "812.12 135.14 646.20 2"};

System.out.println(lines[0].substring(0, lines[0].length() - 1));
for(int i=1; i < lines.length; i++){
    if(lines[i-1].charAt(lines[i-1].length() - 1) != lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length() - 1)){
        System.out.println("S " + lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length() - 1));
    } else {
        System.out.println(lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17 
812.12 135.14 646.18 
S 812.12 135.14 646.19 
812.12 135.14 646.20
```