# How to check 2 charAt(i)

Tags: char, charat

I have this lines:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17 1
812.12 135.14 646.18 1
812.12 135.14 646.19 10
812.12 135.14 646.20 10
812.12 135.14 646.21 100
812.12 135.14 646.22 100
```

I want to delete only the last group so I did code like this:

```
if(lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length())-1>= '0'&&lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1)<= '9'){
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length()-1);
   }

   else if(lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length())>='10'+c&&lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1)<='99'){
   lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length()-2);
        }

   else if(lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length())>='100'&&lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1)<='999){
   lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, lines[i].length()-3);
 }
```

And it's now working for me I need help please

Answer (score 0):

You have characters and trying to compare them as numbers. It doesn't work that way.

A `char` in most higher-level (Java, .NET languages...etc) programming languages follows `UTF-16` format by default. Since each `char` size is `2 bytes` it can follow any encoding you need.

You cannot compare a `char` to `string` and you cannot attempt to put string in char like `'10'`. Those are two characters, not one, it's a `string`.

Now based on your desired output, you would like to remove everything after the last space. To do that, you can use the following code:

```
static void updateLines(String[] lines){
    for(int i=0;i<lines.length; i++){
        // get index of the last space
        int index = lines[i].lastIndexOf(" ");

        // remove everything after the last space
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, index);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lines = new String[]{
      "812.12 135.14 646.17 1",
      "812.12 135.14 646.18 1",
      "812.12 135.14 646.19 10",
      "812.12 135.14 646.20 10",
      "812.12 135.14 646.21 100", 
      "812.12 135.14 646.22 100",
      "812.12 135.14 646.23 1000",
      "812.12 135.14 646.24 1000"
    };

    updateLines(lines);

    for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
        System.out.println(lines[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
812.12 135.14 646.17
812.12 135.14 646.18
812.12 135.14 646.19
812.12 135.14 646.20
812.12 135.14 646.21
812.12 135.14 646.22
812.12 135.14 646.23
812.12 135.14 646.24
```

Is this enough or do you need to compare numbers?

Comment: It isnt working the problem its shown to me its in this line:lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, index);

Comment: "A char in most programming languages follows ASCII format by default": simply not true. Focusing on Java, `char` is a [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) code unit; UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. UTF-16 is used by Java, JavaScript, VB4/5/6, VBA, VBScript, C#, VB, SQL, VBA,,…

Comment: @Dany123 What is the error you're getting? The code is working just fine for me.

Comment: @TomBlodget Sorry you are absolutely right. My mind always goes towards C and C++ where a `char` is `1 byte` long. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working it says a wrong on this line:

```
lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, index);
```

@Everyone

Comment: Can you log back in as @Dany123?